# number inside [] after in orderby in XQuery

Tags: xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-3.0

Following is the query

```
for $x in $books 
where $x/price>=38 
order by ($x/price)[l] 
return ($x/title, $x/price)
```

what is denoted by [1] located after order by($x/price)?

Comment: Please check out some beginner’s tutorials for XPath, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a lower-case-L rather than a digit-one.

If it's really a one `[1]` then it means select the first item in the sequence `$x/price`. I suspect each book has only one price, in which case it's completely redundant.